# Determining the integral intervals for triple integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have 
$$R = \{(x, y, z) : 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le \sqrt{1 − x^2}, 0 ≤ z ≤ x \}$$

and I want to calculate $\int \int_R \int yzdzdydx$. I am given that the answer is $\frac{1}{30}$.

How exactly do I determine the integral range for the second and third integral, since the first integral is probably, as is, the range of $z$; $(0, x)$?

Comment: Could you please state your question more clearly? The last sentence is difficult to parse.

Comment: I was thinking whether or not I have to take the earlier planes into account when applying the range for the integral for the second and third integrals, or if the ranges I've listed in the definition of $R$ work as is for their respective integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inner two integrals, $x$ is a constant and you can treat it as such. That means you first have to compute

$$\int_0^x yzdz = y \cdot \frac{1}{2}x^2$$

Put this inside the next integral

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} y \cdot \frac{1}{2}x^2 dy$$

and so forth.